# ¿Se puede ver en algún lado cuántos usuarios está creciendo Stack Overflow en español por año?

Tags: soporte, estadísticas

Vi que al ranking de usuarios se agregó una barra de navegación que permite ver el ranking de usuarios por año.

Quería saber si se puede ver también de alguna forma el crecimiento de usuarios de Stack Overflow en español. En Stack Overflow en inglés hay una herramienta en donde muchos usuarios (¿y tal vez invitados?) pueden hacer queries para consultar todo tipo de datos acerca del sitio. Si el dato que pregunto no es visible, ¿se puede aquí tambien hacer lo mismo?

Comment: La herramienta que mencionas se llama [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) y, como su nombre indica, contiene datos de todos los sitios de la red. Por tanto, tal y como se ve en la respuesta de toledano, puedes sacar los datos de allí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad no sé si haya alguna estadística oficial, pero se puede ver con la WayBack Machine.

14 de Junio del 2016: 5.688.120 usuarios.

Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20160614225010/https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow

14 de Junio del 2017 (hoy): 7.268.691 usuarios.

Enlace original: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow

La diferencia es: 1.580.571 usuarios nuevos en los últimos 366 días, es decir, un año bisiesto, que fue el 2016 y parte de este.

---

Para el sitio en español.

14 de Junio del 2016: 7.932 usuarios.

WayBack Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20160614232250/https://stackexchange.com/leagues/381/alltime/es-stackoverflow

14 de Junio del 2017 (hoy): 40.281 usuarios.

Enlace original: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/381/alltime/es-stackoverflow

Este año StackOverflow en español sumó 32.349 usuarios.

En los últimos 4 meses, tuvo 15.106 usuarios nuevos, lo que equivale a 45.318 usuarios nuevos por año.

http://web.archive.org/web/20170214011035/http://stackexchange.com/leagues/381/alltime/es-stackoverflow

Comment: Puedes conseguir lo mismo para stackoverflow en español? Ese link muestra para inglés. Intenté yo pero pareciera que el link solo muestra como era el sitio para usuarios no registrados y el ranking se ve solo como usuario registrado

Comment: @Pablo Listo, ya agregué la información para el sitio en español.

Comment: wow como crecio en un año, me parecia

Answer (score 4):

Yo intenté una consulta en http://data.stackexchange.com. Lo que hago es contar el número de usuarios con fecha de creación agrupada por año.

```
SELECT YEAR(u.CreationDate), COUNT(u.id)
FROM Users u
GROUP BY YEAR(u.CreationDate)
ORDER BY(u.CreationDate)
```

Y el resultado está aquí: http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/edit/684764#graph

```
+-------+-----------+
| Tabla | Registros |
+-------+-----------+
|  2015 |     1,783 |
+-------+-----------+
|  2016 |    18,699 |
+-------+-----------+
|  2017 |    19,296 |
+-------+-----------+
```

No estoy muy seguro que el resultado sea el correcto, se me hacen muchos usuarios, pero bueno... si alguien quiere componerla...

Comment: A mí se me hace pocos porque en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate el id del usuario más reciente supera el 47K y en https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday dice que hay 40K

Comment: @Rubén ¿será que los usuarios no registrados computan para el ID pero no en la consulta?

Comment: ahhh, ahora entiendo, eso da la cantidad de usuarios registrados, no la cantidad de usuarios totales. Y sumando daría los 40.000 que figura en la lista, parece correcta

Comment: Este año se espera más de 40.000 usuarios registrados? Impresionante

Comment: Tanto usuarios registrados como no registrados aparecen en la consulta en SEDE (ambos aparecen en la tabla Users). La diferencia entre el máximo ID actual y la cantidad son los **perfiles eliminados**. Es decir que hasta hoy se eliminó el 15.43% de los usuarios, debido a cuentas combinadas, cuentas eliminadas por el usuario, pero principalmente a **[cuentas abandonadas](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/02/16/when-is-an-account-abandoned/)**

Comment: usuarios no registrados? como es eso?

Comment: @Pablo Un usuario puede publicar o realizar cualquier acción en el sitio sin siquiera registrarse. Nada lo obliga a hacerlo, y es una de las características más defendidas en Stack Overflow. A nadie se lo obliga a dejar sus datos antes de aportar conocimiento... Aunque no registrarse sólo tiene desventajas (grandes chances de perder la información de tu cuenta y la autoría de lo que publicaste), es válido para cualquiera que así lo prefiera... Pensar que no aparecían en estos números sólo fue una confusión momentánea: sí, están incluidos.